# Why FixedTargetTracking in Spark AR does not working with colored logo?

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

So. We do a promotional mask for instagram in Spark AR Studio. It should become visible when you hover over the company logo. A texture with a color logo has been added to FixedTargetTracker, but the mask only works when you hover over a black and white logo, if you hover over a color logo it does not work.
Why?

Comment: I do not know the Spark AR Studio but for the ones who do, maybe you can share your method which is working on the black and white logo to start from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use black and white target!